# Adding observable value to another observable

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

As the title says I'm trying to add a value from an observable to another observable.
I'm getting odd results and I'm wondering if I'm doing it the correct way.

**FIDDLE AT THE BOTTOM**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="empiriHelp" data-bind="foreach: empiriHelp"><li data-bind="text: title"></li></ul>
        <ul class="empiricount" data-bind="foreach: $data.empiriLines">
            <li data-bind='event: {mouseover: $root.empiriMouseOver, mouseleave: $root.empiriMouseLeave}'>
                <input class="empiri_amount" data-bind="value: $data.amount"/>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.measurements, value: $data.unit = $root.selectedUnit"></select>
                <input class="empiri_ingredient" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.ingredient, returnKey: $root.empiriAddLine.bind($data, $index())" />
                <div class="empiri_fader">
                    <div class="empiri_add" data-bind="click: $root.empiriAddLine.bind($data, $index())"></div>
                    <div class="empiri_delete" data-bind="click: $root.empiriRemoveLine.bind($data, $index())"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.selectedUnit = ko.observable();

    self.selectedUnit.subscribe(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    });

    self.measurements = ko.observableArray([
                                            ko.observable('Kg'),
                                            ko.observable('g'),
                                            ko.observable('L'),
                                            ko.observable('dl'),
                                            ko.observable('cl'),
                                            ko.observable('tbps'),
                                            ko.observable('tsp'),
                                            ko.observable('cl')
                                            ]);

    self.empiriHelp = [{title: "amount"}, {title: "unit"}, {title: "ingredient"}];
    self.empiriLines = ko.observableArray([{ amount: ko.observable(''), unit: ko.observable(self.measurements[0]),  ingredient: ko.observable('') }]);


    self.empiriAddLine = function(index){
        self.empiriLines.splice(index+1,0,{ amount: ko.observable(''), unit: ko.observable(self.measurements[0]), ingredient: ko.observable('') });
    }

    self.empiriRemoveLine = function(index){
        if(self.empiriLines().length!=1){
            self.empiriLines.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    self.empiriMouseOver = function(data, event){
        $(event.currentTarget).find(".empiri_fader").stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
    }

    self.empiriMouseLeave = function(data, event){
        $(event.currentTarget).find(".empiri_fader").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

The issue is that when the select value changes, it changes value on ALL the empirilines which i don't understand... shouldn't $data be context sensitive and only refer to the current loop item from the foreach? My guess is that I'm binding the observables in the wrong way. I've been hammering my head against this for far too long and my brain is mush.

I cannot brain today, i has the dumb - halp!

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Caw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, just removing the `= $root.selectedUnit` *seems* to do what you want:

`value: $data.unit = $root.selectedUnit`

http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/Y9Caw/2/

Comment: You are a golden God Brandon. I still have ways to go with understanding parameterless extensions. I didn't realise that just adding "value:" would pass the variable into whatever would come next if possible and I was creating workarounds fitting my normal coding patterns...

Comment: That data-bind string is _just_ a javascript object literal you are putting in quotes in your html with a javascript [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) clause set to your viewmodel.  It is the same as if you had written it in javascript like: `with (viewmodel) { var x = { value: unit, text: amount }; ... } ...` Once you realize this (and assuming you know what an object literal is in JavaScript), then it becomes easier to understand the data-bind syntax.